# Edit URL string in iOS

Tags: ios, json, string, url, uiwebview

I have a app which parses a JSON feed for URL links and then stores those the URL in an string. This works fine however, the URL links appear like this:

```
(
"http://instagram.com/p/cCEfu9hUxG/"
)
```

How can I get rid of the brackets and the apostrophe's at the end of the URL?

I need to open the URL in a UIWebView but I can't because of the brackets and the apostrophe's at the ends of the URL.

The information from the JSON feed is being presented in a UITableView. When the user taps one of the cells of the UITableView, the relevant URL for the cell will be stored in a NSString which will then be read by my UIWebView. Here is my code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

NSString *storyLink = [[[[_dataSource objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey:@"entities"] objectForKey:@"urls"] valueForKey:@"expanded_url"];

//[webviewer loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]]];
NSLog(@"\n\n LINK: %@", storyLink);

[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.2];
webviewer.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

I am story the URL in a NSString.

Here is the JSON feed:

```
{
"coordinates": null,
"favorited": false,
"truncated": false,
"created_at": "Sat Aug 25 17:26:51 +0000 2012",
"id_str": "239413543487819778",
"entities": {
  "urls": [
    {
      "expanded_url": "https://dev.twitter.com/issues/485",
      "url": "https://t.co/p5bOzH0k",
      "indices": [
        97,
        118
      ],
      "display_url": "dev.twitter.com/issues/485"
    }
  ],
  "hashtags": [

  ],
  "user_mentions": [

  ]
}
```

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: That looks like the NSLog output of an NSArray. Did already use NSJSONSerialization? Perhaps you just need `NSString *url = jsonObject[0];` ? - Otherwise you have to show more code.

Comment: Not an Xcode question. BTW, this seems like the description of an `NSArray` - in this case, `[array objectAtIndex:0]` does the job.

Comment: @H2CO3  -  I have now updated my post. I tried an NSArray but I don't believe it is what I need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NSLog` output indicates that

```
NSString *storyLink = [[[[_dataSource objectAtIndex: storyIndex]
                         objectForKey:@"entities"]
                        objectForKey:@"urls"]
                       valueForKey:@"expanded_url"];
```

does not return an `NSString` as expected, but an `NSArray`. Could it be that
the value of `"urls"` in the JSON object is an array of dictionaries and not a single dictionary? In that case the following should work:

```
NSString *storyLink = [[[[[_dataSource objectAtIndex: storyIndex]
                           objectForKey:@"entities"]
                          objectForKey:@"urls"]
                         objectAtIndex:0]
                        objectForKey:@"expanded_url"];
```

A more concrete answer might be possible if you show the JSON output.

*Remark:*

```
int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
```

can be simplified to

```
int storyIndex = indexPath.row;
```

(See ["NSIndexPath UIKit Additions"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html).)

**UPDATE:** To localize your problem further, I would recommend that you split your
code into separate commands, and check if the `"urls"` array is empty or not:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [_dataSource objectAtIndex: storyIndex];
NSDictionary *entities = [dict objectForKey:@"entities"];
NSArray *urls = [entities objectForKey:@"urls"];
if ([urls count] > 0) {
    NSDictionary *firstUrl = [urls objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *storyLink = [firstUrl objectForKey:@"expanded_url"];
    NSLog(@"LINK: %@", storyLink);
} else {
    NSLog(@"URLS is an empty array!!");
}
```

If it still crashes, set an "Breakpoint on all Objective-C Exceptions" to check 
where it crashes exactly.

Comment: I believe "urls" is an array of dictionaries. I have updated the post with the JSON feed.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff: That is what H₂CO₃ and I suspected. Did you try my suggested code modification?

Comment: Yes I did try your modification but the app crashes and I get the error:

'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: @Supertecnoboff: Could it be that some "urls" have an empty array as value?

Comment: No I dont think so. When urls is empty, the string which I am storing it in still contains "( )". These brackets are not being added by me.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff: But "( )" is an empty array, that means that you have `"urls": [ ]` somewhere in your JSON response, or that the url has no `expanded_url`.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. If you have a look at my post above, the "expanded_url" string is stored in the "urls" [ ].

Comment: @Supertecnoboff: I have added some code that might be useful to localize the problem.

Comment: OH WOW!!!!!!

Martin, you sir are a god! Thank you so much for your time, your expertise in solving the problem and your solution.

Not only have you helped me better understand what the situation was but you also provided a solution which worked PERFECTLY!!!!!

If I was rich I would pay you lots of money now.... but I'm not... sorry.... :(